# Conditional intersection of sequences

Tags: scala

```
val subjects = Seq("Physics","Maths","English","Chemistry")
val books = Seq("Elementary Physics", " Expert Maths")
```

The 'books' sequence may be empty too.

The idea is to iterate through the subjects - and return the sequence of book for each subject.
Each subject may have AT MOST  one book - and the book name definitely contains the Subject as a substring.

In case, the subject does not have a book - the subject name is returned as is.

So in the above case - the output sequence will be :
Seq("Elementary Physics", " Expert Maths", "English", "Chemistry")

```
subjects.flatMap(s => books.find( b => b.contains(s).getOrElse(s)))
```

The above gives a compile issue - returning a Seq[Char] instead of Seq[String].
Also, this does not handle the case of the books sequence being empty.

What the most concise way to get this done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need just `map`, not `flatMap`:

```
subjects.map(s => books.find(b => b.contains(s)).getOrElse(s))
```

there result of the passed function (`s => books.find(b => b.contains(s)).getOrElse(s)`) is a `String`, so `flatMap` flattens the resulting list of strings into a sequence of characters (`Seq[Char]`).

Check out some examples for `flatMap` [@alvinalexander.com](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/collection-scala-flatmap-examples-map-flatten/)

Comment: How do I inject the the fact that books may be empty though  - taht would throw a NPE here

Comment: @IUnknown empty is not null. You can try using `Option` - i.e. `s => Option(books).find ...`